# Integrate PHP sessions with Vue/Node.js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, vue.js, session-cookies

I have a PHP application which authenticates user, execute MySQL queries and relies on `$_SESSION` cookie.

Everything was working fine but I realized I need to do more with Frontend and hence had to use Vue.js and websockets.

Therefore, I used node.js for primary domain `localhost` (for production sake)

I made PHP API available on `localhost:8080` so that Vue.js could communicate with PHP Backend.

Now, Here's my problem

How can I use/store `$_SESSION ID` in Vue/Websocket and send it along with every request made to PHP server?

I did some research on stackoverflow and found `session_id()` which could return current Session ID but I have no clue about how to integrate PHP with Vue.

**Note: I am using Vue.js (Vue, router, Vuex) and socket.io with Node.js**

Comment: You are doing something. Wrong. Why you need nodeJS?

Comment: I am using some of the frontend libraries that won't work with ES5. I already explained that I need to do more with frontend and I am using Vue, Vue router and Vuex. These are just 3 core libraries. I have over 19 libraries in total (NOT INCLUDING dev dependencies). 
I can't imagine using the same with unpkg.com which will create lots of http request and thus, increasing loading time.

I am also planning to integrate websockets.

Comment: There is a difference between dev dependencies and dependencies. Simply create a script that compiles the final product into the PHP public folder.

Comment: And what about websockets?

Comment: Ask yourself why you use each technology. I believe you are using php as your backend that in the end will serve your frontend files. If you want your websockets to be implemented in nodeJS you could do a cross-domain ( port ) connection by simply specifing the port that the websocket server is running. You might want to edit your question to make it more clear exactly what you are trying to achieve by combining two backend technologies.

Comment: @itsundefined Updated. Thanks for the suggestions. I do realize that the question wasn't clear enough before.

Comment: Node and PHP do the same thing. You shouldn't be using both.

Answer (score 0):

Since the PHP server and the node.JS server is running on two different ports, they are considered as different origins in all browsers. That means that a cookie that was sent from `localhost:8080` will not be sent to any requests made to `localhost:80`. One way to overcome this would be to remove the **http only flag** on session cookies so that you can manually send the cookie via javascript **BUT** that could end up pretty bad if someone manages to run XSS attacks on your site.

Other ways would be **1)** to use only one of the two servers from your front-end and then have the used backend to communicate with the other backend meaning that you could make php available only to the node application or **2)** Redesign PHP to use tokens. From my understanding you are using php as an API and most APIs are designed to use tokens instead of session since you are usually accessing the API from another domain.

Comment: I now wonder how Node communicates with the client? And access cookie data (if any).

Comment: Well, I was thinking to use JWT for tokens. Can you guide me about the same?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on the internet but if you didn't write the PHP code it's gonna be hard to implement it.