# Vue app: how to use public/index.html in .php format?

Tags: php, html, vue.js, session

I wanna add this php script above the html of my index.html file:

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1 || !isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
  $_SESSION['message'] = "Sie müssen Sich zuerst einloggen!";
  header("location: error");    
}else {
    // Leichter zum Lesen
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
}
if(isset($_GET['eventid']) && $_GET['eventid'] != null && $_GET['eventid'] != ""){
  $eventid = $_GET['eventid'];
}else{
  header("location: my_events");
}
?>
```

, but for that I would need to use .php extension. Npm run build doesn't like that. What could be a valid solution, so that I can use php sessions with Vue?

Comment: Do you have to use PHP? If not, did you try and use vue_session - https://github.com/victorsferreira/vue-session There are plenty of returned answers when searching "create php sessions with Vue" that might help, particularly here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49090651/integrate-php-sessions-with-vue-node-js and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798033/how-to-save-users-sessions-with-vuejs/46939335 refers to my comment/question.